# How do I use the transform-class-properties babel plugin when transpiling in the browser

Tags: reactjs, babeljs

My project is not node based so I am transpiling my jsx code in the browser, using the browser.js babel component downloaded from a CDN.

I would like to use the transform-class-properties babel plugin, but I can't figure out how to make it work when using babel in the browser from a CDN.

yes, I know I should use webpack and pre-transpile all my jsx code. I promise I will eventually.

Comment: https://github.com/babel/babel-standalone#usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We must add `data-plugins="transform-class-properties"` to use class properties feature, as shown in the sample below:

```
<script type="text/babel" 
  data-plugins="transform-class-properties" 
  data-presets="react, es2015,stage-2" 
  src="js/main.js">
</script>
```

You can see my codepen code here in  https://codepen.io/ciptohadi79/pen/QxggwO

Answer (score 0):

To spell it out:

```
<script src="https://unpkg.com/babel-standalone@6/babel.min.js"></script>
<!-- Your custom script here -->
<script type="text/babel" data-plugins="">
//
// your jsx goes here
//
</script>
```